# openssl 1.0.2, how to force server to choose only set of ciphers

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, ecdh, ecdhe

I have client server which uses opensl 1.0.2j, and want to force the server to use only the following ciphers.

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
```

My server side code will look like below.

```
method = SSLv23_server_method();
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256");
SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, certFilePath, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, privKeyPath, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)
SSL_accept()
```

The last step ssl_accept fails with

```
here'error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher'
```

I have error checking for each ssl calls in the above code and for clarity purpose not put all the code. If I use "TLSv1.2:!ADH:!NULL" for SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() it works fine.

Edit: The key generated is RSA:4096. Do I need to generate keys differently for ECDH/ECDHE/DHE?

Could you please help me to find why it fails and how can I resolve it?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: Things also depend on what the client sends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this code you don't set any DH parameter so any of these `DHE-*` certificates will not work. Also, no static parameter for ECDH (not ECDHE) are set so no `ECDH-*` ciphers will be used either. This leaves only:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
```

But from these 4 ciphers only two can be used since either you have a RSA certificate (first two ciphers) or an ECC certificate (last two ciphers). Most likely it is an RSA certificate which leaves:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
```

Since you get `no shared cipher` it is likely that your unknown client does not support any of these two ciphers.

> If I use "TLSv1.2:!ADH:!NULL" for SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() it works fine.

With OpenSSL 1.0.2 in a common configuration I see that this set also includes the following ciphers (skipping all DH, ECDH-... as before):

```
AES256-GCM-SHA384
AES256-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES128-SHA256
```

So it is likely that your unknown client use any of these ciphers to connect successfully. For more on this you need to look at the specific client and maybe its configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it is RSA certificate and I used defailt_md as sha256, so it means  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 and ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 also not used? Basically client side also using the same type of certificate and configuration.

Comment: @Naga: the signature algorithm of the certificate is not related to the HMAC of the cipher. These ciphers can be used if the client implements these ciphers and offers these to the server. There are no details known about your client and its configuration so no help can be offered of how to make this unknown client use the ciphers.

Comment: Thanks Steffen Ullrich, After setting the ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 as cipher list on the client side it started working. I appreciate your help.